# Simple: Group By - Having (within this year)

Tags: sql

I am using *MS Access* and I ran into a problem that I'm sure has a simple fix, but I can't find it. I originally had the first column of the query return the "YY-WW" of the date, but that messed with my sorting. So I decided I'd just use "WW" for this year. However, I'm having trouble returning records for just this year with a Group By.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT DATEPART("ww",Total.Dated) AS Week,

Sum(Total.SplitTrailers) AS SplitTrailers, Sum(Total.NonSplitTrailers) AS NonSplitTrailers, 
Sum([Total].[SplitTrailers]+[Total].[NonSplitTrailers]) AS TotalTrailers, 

FORMAT(IIf( [SplitTrailers]<=0,0, [SplitTrailers]/([SplitTrailers]+[NonSplitTrailers])), "Percent") AS [% Frame Dock]

FROM Total
GROUP BY DATEPART("ww",Total.Dated)
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could tell how to return only records from this year or how to sort by a date formatted by "YY-WW".

Thanks!

Comment: I think stating in the title between parentheses when you expect your answer is a good new convention!

Comment: haha I meant it as a description of the problem. Didn't even think of it like that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART("ww",Total.Dated) AS Week,

Sum(Total.SplitTrailers) AS SplitTrailers, Sum(Total.NonSplitTrailers) AS NonSplitTrailers, 
Sum([Total].[SplitTrailers]+[Total].[NonSplitTrailers]) AS TotalTrailers, 

FORMAT(IIf( [SplitTrailers]<=0,0, [SplitTrailers]/([SplitTrailers]+[NonSplitTrailers])), "Percent") AS [% Frame Dock]

FROM Total where Year(Total.Date)=Year(GetDate())--this will return the current year data
GROUP BY DATEPART("ww",Total.Dated)
```

Comment: Wow, I got hung up so much on adding a HAVING clause that I just blanked on using a WHERE. Embarrassing! Thank you. I just had to change GetDate() to Date().

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add a WHERE clause?

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART("ww",Total.Dated) AS Week,
    Sum(Total.SplitTrailers) AS SplitTrailers, 
    Sum(Total.NonSplitTrailers) AS NonSplitTrailers, 
    Sum([Total].[SplitTrailers]+[Total].[NonSplitTrailers]) AS TotalTrailers, 
    FORMAT(IIf( [SplitTrailers]<=0,0, [SplitTrailers]/([SplitTrailers]+[NonSplitTrailers])), "Percent") AS [% Frame Dock]
FROM Total
WHERE Year(Total.Dated) = Year(Date())
GROUP BY DATEPART("ww",Total.Dated)
```

Comment: Wow, I got hung up so much on adding a HAVING clause that I just blanked on using a WHERE. Embarrassing! Thank you.